# Loading Parent Child data using Entity Framework stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two stored procedures, one to load parent data and other to load child data. Is there anyway to do this in a better way? Please see code below.

```
    public partial class Product
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ProductionNo { get; set; }
        public string UniqueIdentificationNo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Process> Processes { get; set; }
    }

    public List<GetProductsBetween_Result> GetProductsBetween(DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        var products = DbContext.GetProductsBetween(startDate, endDate).ToList();

        foreach(var product in products)
        {
            product.Processes = DbContext.GetWaitingTime(product.Id).ToList();
        }

        return products;
    }
```

Comment: Can you specify whats parent and child here in this context?

Answer (score 0):

This entire scenario can be rewritten using Linq(Language Intergrated Query).
You can apply eager loading to fetch the Processes of a product. This is similar
to sql joins which Linq provides, such a state that code is optimised and foreachs
and hits to the server can be reduced

```
var products = from u in dbContext.Product.Include(u => u.Processes)
            select new ProductView
            {
                item1 = XXX, 
        item2 = yyy
            };

var newdata = user.ToList().where("some lambda expressions")
```

with conditions to filter date

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a really complex search that had to return the full tree of an object.

What you need to do is:

1. Make a stored procedure that returns in only one call multiple result sets for the root object and for all its dependent objects:

i.e. (add your own conditions)

```
SELECT p.* FROM Products p WHERE p.Name LIKE '%test%';
SELECT DISTINCT r.* FROM Processes r INNER JOIN Products p ON p.id = r.idProduct WHERE p.Name LIKE '%test%';
```

2. After the return, re-attach the parent objects with its childs as described in this article:

https://blogs.infosupport.com/ado-net-entity-framework-advanced-scenarios-working-with-stored-procedures-that-return-multiple-resultsets/

You will need to iterate each Product from the first result set and attach its Processes.

This should be much faster since you only make one round-trip to the database and less queries.